# Print triangle of *'s in Assembly Language (LC-3)

Tags: loops, assembly, lc3, machine-code

I am trying to print a triangle of asterisks based on a value of N. The code I have here will just print an entire row of N *'s. The end result i am looking for is:

```
*
**
***
****
If N = 4
```

The code I have right now

```
       .ORIG x3000

        LD   R1, N
        NOT  R1, R1
        ADD  R1, R1, #1 ; R1 = -N

        AND     R2, R2, #0  ; R2 = 0
LOOP    ADD R3, R2, R1  ; while (R2 < N)
        BRzp     
        LD   R0, STAR   ; R0 = *
        OUT             ; Write *
        LEA  R0, NEWLN  ; R2 = R2 + 1
        PUTS
        ADD  R2, R2, #1 ; 
        BRnzp    LOOP
ELOOP
        LEA  R0, NEWLN
        PUTS

STOP    HALT        

N       .FILL    4
STAR    .FILL    x2A
NEWLN   .STRINGZ "\n"
```

Can anyone help me out with accomplishing this?

Comment: How does that code do (or not do) what you want?

Comment: The code here will print N *'s in a single row

Comment: So your call to `NEWLN` does not work, or is possibly called at the wrong time? Did you step through the code with a debugger?

Comment: No, the new line works for the way this code is set up, I now want to modify it to act the way I need it to now.

Comment: If the PUTS worked, you should get the asterisks in a single column. Maybe you should put out the newline just like you put out the asterisk. Then you can make an outer loop that gives different values for r2 to print different lengths of asterisk-bars. Oh, and take the newline printing out of the inner loop and put it after the loop.

Answer (score -1):

```
;; Author: Chris Wickell


.ORIG x3000

    LD   R1, N
    NOT  R1, R1
    ADD  R1, R1, #1 ; R1 = -N

    AND     R2, R2, #0  ; R2 = holds number of *'s to be printed

    LOOP    LEA  R0, NEWLN

    PUTS    

    ADD R3, R2, R1  ; while (R2 < N)

    BRzp ELOOP

    ADD  R5, R5, #1 ;

    ADD  R4, R4, #1

    FLOOP   LD   R0, STAR   ; R0 = *

    OUT             ; Write *
    ADD R5, R5, #-1

    BRp FLOOP

    ADD R5, R4, #0

    ADD  R2, R2, #1 ;

    BRnzp    LOOP
    ELOOP
    LEA  R0, NEWLN

    PUTS

    STOP    HALT        

N       .FILL    6

STAR    .FILL    x2A

NEWLN   .STRINGZ "\n"
```

Answer (score -1):

## make_COM

; COM file is loaded at CS:0100h
ORG 100h

MOV AH,0EH
CALL A4
CALL A3
CALL A2
CALL A1
JMP STOP

A4: MOV AL,41H

```
INT 10H
```

A3: 
    MOV AL,41H
    INT 10H
A2:
    MOV AL,41H
    INT 10H
A1:
    MOV AL,41H
    INT 10H
    MOV AL,0DH
    INT 10H
    MOV AL,0AH
    INT 10H
RET
STOP:
.EXIT

;just change 41h(A) to *(in hexadecimal)

Answer (score -2):

## make_COM

; COM file is loaded at CS:0100h
ORG 100h

MOV AH,0EH
CALL A4
CALL A3
CALL A2
CALL A1
JMP STOP

A4: MOV AL,41H

```
INT 10H
```

A3: 
    MOV AL,41H
    INT 10H
A2:
    MOV AL,41H
    INT 10H
A1:
    MOV AL,41H
    INT 10H
    MOV AL,0DH
    INT 10H
    MOV AL,0AH
    INT 10H
RET
STOP:
.EXIT